# Calculate time difference between each transaction using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to find out the time difference between each transactions for each unique `machine_id` right now but have trouble calculate the time difference for each group respectively. `event_date` has a type of integer while `event_time` has a type of object

[image]

Comment: "event_time has a type of object."  That's the dtype (data type) of the Pandas column.  It is used for any type of Python data which is not a number or a string.  If you extract just one element from the event_time column, what data type is it?

Comment: the data type is string

Answer (score 1):

Make a **datetime** column as -

convert ***event_date*** to datetime format

```py
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'], 
                                  format='%Y%m%d',
                                  errors='ignore')\
                                  .astype(str)
```

combine date and time column

```py
df['event_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(\
        df['event_date'] + ' '+ df['event_time'])
```

then find difference on this column by grouping on `matching_id`

```py
df.groupby('matching_id')['event_datetime']\
       .apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

Comment: hi, can you elaborate on find the difference on this column by grouping on mathicn_id. and also since event_date has a type of int and event_time has a type of str, I think I cannot simply add them together. However, if I add str(), it also does not work

Comment: hi, I have edited the answer, the `event_date` will be converted to datetime format first then it will be combined with `event_time`. please try now.

Answer (score 0):

May be it might help you:

```
In [1]: time.time()
Out[1]: 1347517739.44904

In [2]: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
Out[2]: '2012-09-13 06:31:43'
```

replace "%Y-%m-%d" with your date and "%H:%M:%S" with your time
And then you can do the same with next transaction and try to subtract them.

Comment: I'm interested in learning how to restrict the time difference calculation for transaction with the same machine id. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: and how I do the subtraction all at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
diff_ser = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['event_time'],\
                          format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').diff()
```

PS: you can do something like this. haven't tested it. it may have error.